# AngularJS NG-Repeat Select and set selected on page load?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am generating a grid thru Angular and each row will have a dropdown. I want the dropdown to populate with data from the server which is working but during page load, it needs to set the selected item of each dropdown to the value of the property it's bound to. Simple example below...

Class CategoryField
  ID
  Name
  CategoryID = 2

Select
  Option1 text=Category A  value=1
  Option2 text=Category B value=2 <--- This item should be selected on load.

The code i have appears to have a selected attribute on an item in each dropdown from page source but the dropdown is loading and selecting the blank item angular adds. Code below for grid...UPDATED CODE BELOW

```
<div ng-app="CategoryFieldsApp">

Search:<input ng-model="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" />

@using (Html.BeginForm("CategoryFields", "Maintenance", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div ng-controller="CategoryFieldsCtrl">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th width="200">Category</th>
                    <th ng-click="sort('Name')" width="200">Name</th>
                    <th width="150">Active</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="CategoryFieldGrid">
                <tr dir-paginate="categoryField in categoryFields|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:10">
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="CategoryFields[{{$index}}].CategoryFieldID" ng-model="categoryField.CategoryFieldID" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="hdnCategoryID" type="hidden" name="CategoryFields[{{$index}}].CategoryID" />
                        <select ng-model="categoryField.CategoryID" ng-options="category.CategoryID as category.Name for category in categories"></select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="CategoryFields[{{$index}}].Name" ng-model="categoryField.Name" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="active checkBox checkbox-inline" value="{{categoryField.Active}}" ng-model="categoryField.Active" name="CategoryFields[{{$index}}].Active" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" ng-click="remove($index)" value="Remove" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <dir-pagination-controls max-size="5"
                                 direction-links="true"
                                 boundary-links="true">
        </dir-pagination-controls>
        <br />
        <a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="add()">Add Category Field</a>
        <input class="btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" value="Save" />
    </div>
}
```

```
<script>
var App = angular.module('CategoryFieldsApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']).controller('CategoryFieldsCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("@Url.Action("GetCategoryFields", "Maintenance")").success(function (response) {
        $scope.categoryFields = response;  //ajax request to fetch data into $scope.data
    });
    $http.get("@Url.Action("GetCategories", "Maintenance")").success(function (response) {
        $scope.categories = response;  //ajax request to fetch data into $scope.data
    });

    $scope.sort = function (keyname) {
        $scope.sortKey = keyname;   //set the sortKey to the param passed
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse; //if true make it false and vice versa
    }

    $scope.remove = function (index) {
        $scope.categoryFields.splice(index, 1);
    };

    $scope.add = function () {
        $scope.categoryFields.push({
            CategoryFieldID: 0,
            CategoryID: 0,
            Name: '',
            Active: true,
            ShowRemove: true
        });
    };
});


//$(document).ready(function () {

//    $('#CategoryFieldGrid tr').each(function (i, row) {
//        var categoryID = $(row).find('.hdnCategoryID').val();
//        console.log(categoryID);
//        $(row).find('.ddlCategories').val(categoryID);
//    });

//    $('.ddlCategories').on('change', function (e) {
//        var hidden = $(e.target).closest('tr').find('.hdnCategoryID');
//        $(hidden).val($(e.target).closest('tr').find('.ddlCategories').val());
//    });
//});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using `ng-options`? It could be used to replace the explicit definition of your options:

```
<select ng-model="categoryField.CategoryID" ng-options="category.CategoryID as category.Name for category in categories"></select>
```

if you break down the expression we pass to ng-options, we're setting the value of the selected item to the `CategoryID` property, the visible name of each option to the category `Name` property, and we're passing in all the categories defined `$scope.categories` as options:

```
"category.CategoryID as category.Name for category in categories"
```

Here's a working example I put together: http://plnkr.co/edit/CXZaUYfqcIv7PbeUrT9j?p=preview

Comment: I'll give this a shot. I had done an example with ng-options prior to the above code and had similar results..might of missed something then too.

Comment: Should this also update the value when you make a new selection from the loaded value? Not seeing it change in chrome dev tools.

Comment: this should update the ng-model, `categoryField.CategoryID`

Comment: I seen your example plunker updating the ng-model, however when i implemented it in my code it fails to update. Should this be due to creating this select for every row in the grid?

Comment: i updated the code and provided the angular script also this time. It sets the values on load but when i change the option, it doesn't update the value and nothing is being posted back on form post.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the other side of the bindings so that the mvc model was updated for post back. I simply created a hidden field that was bound to the same property. When angular's ng-model updates, it updated the value of the hidden field also. Below is the syntax for those who needs it.

```
                            <input class="hdnCategoryFieldID" type="hidden" name="CategoryFieldApprovers[{{$index}}].CategoryFieldID" value="{{categoryFieldApprover.CategoryFieldID}}" />
                        <select ng-model="categoryFieldApprover.CategoryFieldID" ng-options="categoryField.CategoryFieldID as categoryField.Name for categoryField in categoryFields"></select>
```